# applescript & Mac Mail - extract content from mail body to an excel spreadsheet - not all content extracts

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

Using Applescript I'm trying to extract the body content of all emails from a specific folder inside Mac Mail into a excel spreadsheet. I can do this to a point with the code below, but for some reason not all the body content (just text) is extracted, it cuts off at a crucial point, just before or in the middle of grabbing the target email address, typical!

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set LinkRemoval to make new workbook

    set theSheet to active sheet of LinkRemoval

    set formula of range "A1" of theSheet to "Date"

end tell





tell application "Mail"

    set theRow to 2

    set theAccount to "Exchange"

    get account theAccount

    set theMessages to messages of mailbox "Inbox/Target Folder" of account "Exchange"

    repeat with aMessage in theMessages

        my SetMessage(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)

        set theRow to theRow + 1

    end repeat

end tell



on SetMessage(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        set theRange to "A" & theRow

        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theMessage

    end tell

end SetMessage
```

I've been told that extracting it to a CSV file might help but I don't know how to do this with Applescript... Could anyone help? I'm new the the language!

John

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem is just with the extraction from Mail (and not sending to Excel). So here, this will extract email content from a selection of messages. You need to declare the variables for the account and the mailbox.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

on ParseEmailMessages(theMsg)
    tell application "Mail"
        set subj to subject of theMsg
        set DateName to date received of theMsg
        set SenderN to sender of theMsg
        set SenderName to extract name from sender of theMsg
        set senderAddress to extract address from sender of theMsg
        set BodyMessage to content of theMsg
        set IDName to id of theMsg as string
        try
            set RecipientsAddress to address of recipients of theMsg
            set RecipientsName to name of recipients of theMsg
        on error
            set RecipientsN to ""
        end try
        set AttachmentsV to mail attachment of theMsg
    end tell
    set Msg to {subj:subj, RecipientsName:RecipientsName, RecipientsAddress:RecipientsAddress, DateName:DateName, SenderN:SenderN, senderAddress:senderAddress, SenderName:SenderName, BodyMessage:BodyMessage, IDName:IDName, AttachmentsV:AttachmentsV}
    return Msg
end ParseEmailMessages


on run
    tell application "Mail"
        set theMessages to messages of the mailbox TheMailbox of TheAccount
        repeat with i from 1 to count of theMessages
            set theMsg to item i of theMessages
            set Msg to ParseEmailMessages(theMsg)
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

If you need help with Excel, just let me know.